# charts as data points(markers) in arcgis javascript API

Tags: geospatial, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a requirement where the marker points(graphics) on the esri map should be a dynamic pie chart with a data set of its own.

Is this possible using ArcGIS javascript API?

Comment: please remove the 'esri-leaflet' tag from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends, how you want to use it. If you just want to visualize the points as Charts, the most simplest way is to create the symbology in ArcMap and host its as a map service. According to the [supported functionality](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/supported-functionality-in-map-services.htm) for ArcGIS Server. Charts are also supported.

If you cannot create a service, and would want to create charts runtime in Javascript. Then the only option would be to create the charts as images and add the Point on map with PictureMarkerSymbol.